# Embedding into Permutation Representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $\rho$ be irreducible representation  of group $G$. 
How one can characterize all subgroups $H< G$ such that $\rho$ can be embedded into permutation representation $F^X$, where $X=G/H$.

Comment: Minor edits.   I guess *F* is the underlying field.  Note that the characteristic of the field and whether *G* is finite might influence the answer or the methods used.   Permutation representations most often come up for finite groups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the following adjointness (a form of Frobenius reciprocity):

$Hom_G(\rho,F^X) = Hom_H(\rho,trivial).$

Thus $\rho$ embeds in $F^X$ if and only if $\rho$ admits a non-trivial $H$-fixed quotient.

(If $H$ is finite and $F$ has characteristic zero, or at least prime to the order
of $H$, so that $\rho$ is semi-simple
as an $H$-representation, then this is equivalent to requiring that $\rho$ have a 
non-trivial $H$-fixed subrepresentation.)

(Note also that a non-zero $G$-equivariant map out of $\rho$ is automatically injective,
because $\rho$ is irreducible.)

Comment: Note also that, if $\chi$ is the character of $\rho$, then $Hom_H(\rho, trivial)$ has dimension $1/|H| \sum_{h \in H} \chi(h)$.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I use this fact 5000 times a day.